# Tracking of external links with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a problem with tracking external links. It's not like my solution does not work at all, the problem is, it works only in very few cases. Like 1% of clicks is actually tracked in Analytics. First I had the timeout set to 100ms and thought it might be too short, but even with 500 nothing changed.

Anyone has an idea what might go wrong here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'domain.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) { 
try { 
    ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action');
} catch(err){}

setTimeout(function() {
document.location.href = link.href;
}, 500);
}
```

My links look like this:

> a class="post" onclick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'domain.com');" href="http://www.external.com" rel="nofollow">Click here

In Analytics I check in goals for "category = Outbound Links"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code, but you should be using Universal Analytics built-in `hitCallback` function:

HTML:

```
<a class="post" onclick="recordOutboundLinks('Outbound Link', this.href); return false;" href="http://www.external.com" rel="nofollow">Click here</a>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function recordOutboundLinks(category, link){ 
try { 
    ga('send', 'event', category, link, {'hitCallback': function() {
        document.location.href = link;
    }});
} catch(err){}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Great, glad to hear. If this solved your issue, please check the answer.

Comment: Shouldn't this also feature a setTimeout in case hitCallback never fires.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is that you aren't preventing the default event for the link, so it doesn't matter what you set the timeout to.. your function gets executed but then the browser proceeds to execute the default event for the link: that is to follow the target specified in the href. You can update your code to this:

link (noticed use of `event` instead of `this`):

```
<a class="post" onclick="recordOutboundLink(event, 'Outbound Links', 'domain.com');" href="http://www.external.com" rel="nofollow">Click here</a>
```

function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function recordOutboundLink(event, category, action) { 
  try { 
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default link action
    ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action');
  } catch(err){}

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.location.href = event.target.href;
  }, 200); 
}
</script>
```

In my experience, a timeout of 100-200ms should be enough to get GA code to ping but you may have to play with that a little yet, because it's not guaranteed. Alternatively, you *can* write code to hook into when ga finishes its thing, and it would be easier if you are already using a framework like jQuery.. But overall I agree with **Blexy** in that you should switch to UA which provides a callback function (and in his example, he prevents the default by appending `return false` in the onclick).